# Renaming files in multiple subfolders

Tags: powershell, cmd

I have 100 folders that are incremental. E.g.

```
'20D, 0.5B001'...'20D, 0.5B002'
```

...all the way to

```
'20D, 0.5B100'
```

Each of those folders contains files that have the same incremental names. E.g. `'Test_C1S0002001'...'Test_C1S0002002'` etc.

I want to rename every file in each of these folders to `'002001'` I.e. just get rid of `'Test_C1S0'` in every one of these subfolders. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you made any attempts so far? Is there any particular bit you are stuck with that you can show?

Answer (score 0):

```
gci 'c:\path\' -File -Recurse | ren -NewName { $_ -replace 'Test_C1S0', '' }
```

(untested)

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.

Answer (score 0):

What [TessellatingHeckler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31054285/3829407) has should work perfectly fine. You don't need regex for this as you are removing a simple string from the beginning of the line. So using the same logic...

```psh
Get-ChildItem "C:\temp" -Recurse -File | Rename-Item {($_.Name).TrimStart("Test_C1S0")}
```

If you don't have PowerShell at least v3.0 then you would need to do this.

```psh
Get-ChildItem "C:\temp" -Recurse | Where-Object{!$_.PSIsContainer} | Rename-Item {($_.Name).TrimStart("Test_C1S0")}
```